# The polynominal P is defined as $P ( x ) = x^3+ 4x^2 + 5x + 3$

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $P$ is defined as $P ( x ) = x^3+ 4x^2 + 5x + 3$

Express $P ( x )$ in the form $P ( x ) = ( x + 2 ) ( x^2+ ax + b ) + c$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are whole numbers.

any one tell me the idea of solution ♥ ♥ ♥

Comment: Just use polynomial long division. Divide $P$ by $x+2$.

Comment: Divide $P(x)$ by $x+2$ using long division

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is $(x+2)(x^2+2x+1)+1$.

$x^3+4x^2+5x+3$

$=x^2(x+2)+2x^2+5x+3$

$=x^2(x+2)+2x(x+2)+x+3$

$=x^2(x+2)+2x(x+2)+(x+2)+1$

$=(x+2)(x^2+2x+1)+1$

Comment: Abhra Abir Kundu thanks for your speed answer you are smart ♥ ♥ ♥

Comment: now i have a variety of answers thanks all >>  all the answer is useful  happy mother day ♥ ♥

Answer (score 1):

Hint: open up parentheses on the right hands side and compare coefficients:

$$(x+2)(x^2+ax+b)+c=x^3+(a+2)x^2+(b+2a)x+(2b+c)$$

Thus, for example, $\,a+2=4\;,\;\;b+2a=5\,$ and etc.

Comment: DonAntonio thanks < now i try to apply your useful idea

Answer (score 1):

If 
$P ( x ) = ( x + 2 ) ( x^2+ ax + b ) + c$ 
then $c=P(-2)$, right?

Now, when you find $c$ divide $P(x)-c=( x + 2 ) ( x^2+ ax + b )$ with $x+2$ to find $x^2+ ax + b$.

Comment: ♥ ♥ ♥ thanks  P..

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a horner scheme to divide the polynomial by $(x+2)$

Comment: thanks long tom but what is the mean of horner scheme

Comment: it's a faster way to execute polynomial division (when dividing by a polynomial of 1st degree)

Comment: thank i love the faster ways because the exam is need to be faster ♥  ♥  ♥ thanks long tom

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method